# Вывод значений переменных в php

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Проблема заключается в следующем.
Как видно по коду, который я прикрепил, я спарсил данные с другого сайта и записал их в 2 переменные. Первая это $articul, в нее попадает много значений, точней все значения согласно заданным условиям парсинга. Более 1500 артикулов.
Другая - это $price. Тоже самое что и с $articul. 1500 цен, каждая из которых соответствует артикулу.
Все эти данные мне нужно сохранять в database.txt или database.xls.
Так вот, при выводе:

```html
echo '<table class=container border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0"><th>Артикул</th><th>Цена товара</th>'; 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$articul.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
```

Показывается все в строку. Вы видите это на скриншоте.
Мне нужно, чтобы значения переменных записывались в столбик друг напротив друга.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?php 
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
 echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";

function parser ($url,$start,$end) {

 if ($start < $end) {
 
  $file = file_get_contents($url);
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
   foreach ($doc->find('.product-list') as $position) {
    $position = pq($position);

    $articul = $position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text();
    $price = $position->find('.actions .price')->html();

    $file = 'database.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $articul));
   }
    echo '<table class=container border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0"><th>Артикул</th><th>Цена товара</th>'; 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$articul.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';


   $next = $doc->find('.pagination .active')->next()->find('a')->attr('href');
  
  if ( !empty($next) ) {
   $start++;
   parser($next, $start, $end);
  }
 } 
}



$url = "https://www.agro-center.com.ua/combines-a/spare-parts-for-grain-harvesters/john-deere-c/?limit=200";
$start = 0;
$end = 1;
parser($url,$start,$end);

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты форматируешь все посредством html. Корректно это будет отображаться если ты будешь сохранять файл как html и просматривать его в браузере. Для  того чтобы правильно все записалось в файл .txt лучше использовать следующий код

```
$inFile = 'Артикул '.$articul.' Цена товара'.$price.'\r\n';
```

После чего дописываешь эту переменную к файлу .txt

Для html нужен следующий вид, сначала лучше заготовку

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Parser</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Артикул </td>
      <td> Цена </td>
    </tr>
```

После чего получив данные записываешь в переменную

```
$inFile = "<tr><td>".$articul."</td><td>".$price."</td></tr>";
```

После чего эту переменную дописываешь в конец к файлу. После чего еще дописываешь

```
    </table>
  <body>
</html>
```

Comment: извините, я не совсем понял куда дописывать
 </table>
  <body>
</html>

И какой вид будет иметь файл html? Если можно, покажите пожалуйста.

Comment: в конец файла, после окончания парсинга